# Insert record for each pair in two selects

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, postgresql, sql-insert

Currently I have 3 tables. Let's say users, permissions and table linking them both (because of `n` to `n` relationship) which can be called usr_prm. Now I have a group of users which should get certain set of permissions. I can define both groups in terms of sql selects. But now I'm wondering is there a way to do this operation in a single insert query? So far I have come up with the following solution, but this means running `x` queries, where `x` is the number of permissions I need to add.

To add to the complexity I can say that set of users is chosen based on their already assigned permissions. So we can express it simple as: Add set of permissions (i.e. PERM_1_1, PERM_1_2) to the users who already have a permission PERM_1.

I'm using PostgreSQL DB now but I hope there is universal solution because our application also supports SQL Server and Oracle DBs for some clients and it may come handy to use this script on their DBs too.

What am I currently using:

```sql
insert into usr_prm (user_id, permission_id)
select users.id, (select id from permissions where name="PERM_1_1")
from users
    inner join usr_prm on usr_prm.user_id = users.id
    inner join permissions on permissions.id = usr_prm.permission_id
where permissions.name = "PERM_1"
  and ...

insert into usr_prm (user_id, permission_id)
select users.id, (select id from permissions where name="PERM_1_2")
from users
    inner join usr_prm on usr_prm.user_id = users.id
    inner join permissions on permissions.id = usr_prm.permission_id
where permissions.name = "PERM_1"
  and ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
insert into usr_prm (user_id, permission_id)
    select up.user_id, p2.id
    from usr_prm up inner join
         permissions p
         on p.id = up.permission_id cross join
         (select p2.*
          from permissions p2
          where p2.name in ('PERM_1_1', 'PERM_1_2', . . .)
         ) p2
    where p.name = 'PERM_1';
```

Based on your sample code, you don't need the `users` table, unless that is needed for additional conditions.

Comment: I knew there should be better way than mine but wasn't expecting something that simple. It's working great. Now I just have understand what's going on here. :) Btw. there are no other conditions on users.